# Asa G Suite Admin, getting email access for a list of users for a "Project" in an Existing Org Unit

Tags: google-calendar-api, gmail-api, google-workspace, google-admin-settings-api, google-contacts-api

According to the docs, Google Apps domain administrators can grant service accounts domain-wide authority to access user data on behalf of users in the domain. My understating is this gives service account authority to access data for all users inside the domain. Is there a way to restrict which users service account has access to? If yes, how? Additionally, is there a way to create a "Project" within an existing Organization Unit so that I can move users within that project and then within a service account so that only a list of email accounts that are placed in it.

For example, an application that uses Gmail API and Google Calendar API to view events from the email and calendars of specific list of users in a Google Apps domain.

Can google apps administrator authorize application for access to some but not all users?

Comment: The answer is no to both of your questions. Service accounts with Domain-Wide delegation cannot be restricted based upon certain users, groups, etc. From your question, it is not clear what your end-goal is.

Comment: Hi John. Thank you for your response. The end goal as a G Suite Admin is to use a service account to access a list of user accounts (say a list of 5 users) and be forbidden to access any other users’ accounts. For e.g. As a G Suite Admin of Company XYZ, I want to enable Gmail and Calendar API for a service account only for a list of user accounts (say a list of 10 users of XYZ) and not grant access to other users of XYZ. After enabling API's, access would be granted through a JSON file. However, I can't find a way to implement this. Is there a solution or any alternative way for this problem?

Comment: I am not aware of any Google method to accomplish this. Think of a service account with Domain-Wide delegation as the root user (in Unix terms). You cannot restrict these rights. An idea would be to create a broker. The broker has the Domain-Wide service account. Create another service account that sends requests to the broker. The broker then grants (performs the request) or not based upon rules and logic you create. In essence, you would be creating an IAM layer on top of Google IAM.